# Execute mongodb command on pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Hello : i have the following script on mongodb :

```
db.shipping.find({"dateCreated":{$type:"string"}}).forEach(
function(doc){
doc["dateCreated"]=new Date(doc["dateCreated"]);
db.shipping.save(doc);
})
```

I need  to execute in pymongo

Its a simple function to parse strings to date and i want to add this task to apache airflow

Regards

Comment: It seems like you are doing an update here. Am I correct in assuming this?

Comment: yes , first i filter only the docs where date_created is string and then save the doc parsed

Comment: You can just do an update like so `db.shipping.updateMany({'dateCreated': {'$type':"string"}}, {'$set': {"dateCreated": new Date('$dateCreated')}})` Also what error are you getting when you try to execute what you have using pymongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of your code in pymongo would be:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from dateutil.parser import parse

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

for doc in db.shipping.find({'dateCreated':{'$type':'string'}}):
    db.shipping.update_one({'_id': doc.get('_id')}, {'$set': { 'dateCreated': parse(doc.get('dateCreated'))}})
```